# How to read Specific Data from Gmail Body with Python?

Tags: python, gmail

I try the gmail reader using Python from this link `https://github.com/abhishekchhibber/Gmail-Api-through-Python` and now i want to read every email from specific data.
For Example like this :

```
Name : John Doe
Address : Las Vegas
City : New York
```

I want only print for the output is `City : New York` .. how to solve this ?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As having been mentioned in the Github repository, the output will be a dictionary like that.

```
output = {
              'Name' : 'John Doe',
              'Address' : 'Las Vegas',
              'City' : 'New York'
         }
```

Now you just need to print out what you want, for e.g:

```
print("City: " + output.get("City"))
```

`output.get("City")` will return you the value of the key `City`.

Comment: I am sorry , i am newer in Python. Can you explain the full detail how i can use this script ?

Comment: @Rai I just edit my answer. You can read more information about `dictionary` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: I got error if i paste `print("City: " + output.get("City"))` the error like this  `('Total unread messages in inbox: ', '10')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmail_read.py", line 56, in <module>
    print("City: " + output.get("City"))
NameError: name 'output' is not defined` . I have paste it under the `print ("Total unread messages in inbox: ", str(len(mssg_list)))` Can you help me where i must paste it ?

Comment: `output` is just the name of the variable here, you should change it to make it same as your code.